# Tracking the redirection path of URLs in javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, firefox-addon

I am trying to find number of redirections of a requested url in a browser, and if possible want to track the redirected path of that URL through javascript.

For example, if i request 'A' in my browser.assume the redirection flow as A->B->C->D. Means,it gets redirected to 'D'. In this case i need to get three 301 redirect status codes and one 200 ok status code.

I tried the below method in my addon.js(and made an addon to firefox browser).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
var StatusValue = req.status;
```

It is giving 200 ok (I think it is of final url).

Is it possible to get all 301 redirects of a URL through Javascript.

Thanks,

Comment: interesting question. my gut instinct is to say that you would need to create/update a cookie or session variable at each link in the redirection chain, as each redirect constitutes a new request, and therefore a new response.

Comment: Here's some info: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#HTTP_notifications
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannelEventSink

Comment: can u explain briefly, how to catch the each links in a redirected chain. because im getting the "redirected website"(last one in the redirection chain) content in my browser.and 200 ok status for that.            Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nsIXMLHttpRequest` interface](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/d254c07f3301/content/base/public/nsIXMLHttpRequest.idl#l103) has a member `channel` (accessible to extensions only) of type [`nsIChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel). You can assign your own callbacks to its `notificationCallbacks` property and implement [`nsIChannelEventSync` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannelEventSink) to receive redirection events. Something along these lines:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location);

var oldNotifications = req.channel.notificationCallbacks;
var oldEventSink = null;
req.channel.notificationCallbacks =
{
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([
      Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor,
      Components.interfaces.nsIChannelEventSink]),

  getInterface: function(iid)
  {
    // We are only interested in nsIChannelEventSink, return the old callbacks
    // for any other interface requests.
    if (iid.equals(Ci.nsIChannelEventSink))
    {
      try {
        oldEventSink = oldNotifications.QueryInterface(iid);
      } catch(e) {}
      return this;
    }

    if (oldNotifications)
      return oldNotifications.QueryInterface(iid);
    else
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
  },

  asyncOnChannelRedirect: function(oldChannel, newChannel, flags, callback)
  {
    var type = null;
    if (flags & Components.interfaces.nsIChannelEventSink.REDIRECT_TEMPORARY)
      type = "temporary";
    else if (flags & Components.interfaces.nsIChannelEventSink.REDIRECT_PERMANENT)
      type = "permanent";
    else if (flags & Components.interfaces.nsIChannelEventSink.REDIRECT_INTERNAL)
      type = "internal";

    Components.utils.reportError("Redirect from " + oldChannel.URI.spec + " " +
                                 "to " + newChannel.URI.spec + " " +
                                 (type ? "(" + type + ")" : ""));

    if (oldEventSink)
      oldEventSink.asyncOnChannelRedirect(oldChannel, newChannel, flags, callback);
    else
      callback.onRedirectVerifyCallback(Cr.NS_OK);
  }
};

req.send(null);
```

This code makes sure to always call the old notification callbacks while logging any calls to `nsIChannelEventSync.asyncOnChannelRedirect`.

For reference: [nsIInterfaceRequestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIInterfaceRequestor), [XPCOMUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm).

Comment: Superb! I just needed this! Thank you! Is there some way to block the redirect? (probably is I'm going to start invesitgating now, just being lazy and asking before i start) Also is it possible to do something like this from ChromeWorker?

Comment: @Noitidart: Yes, you don't have to pass NS_OK to the callback, you can also give is `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` for example. ChromeWorker won't work, it cannot access XPCOM.

Comment: Thanks! Should doing `callback.onRedirectVerifyCallback(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED)` differ from what it does when we `throw` as noted on the DXR page - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsIChannelEventSink.idl#94 ? Asking because I might have screwed something up lol

Comment: @Noitidart: Not really, it should do the same thing. However, most error codes will show up in Error Console, but `NS_BIND‌​ING_ABORTED` will not.

Comment: Thanks @Palant I think why it was logging for me was I was not doing `throw Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED` but I was doing `throw new Error(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED)`. I'll try that now. No matter what in my tests when I do `callback.onRedirectVerifyCallback` with `Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED` it fatally ends it. So the events no longer fire so my load event listener doesn't happen. Unlike if I throw. So this is what happens with callback - `"NS_BINDING_ABORTED: Component returned failure code: 0x804b0002 (NS_BINDING_ABORTED) [nsIAsyncVerifyRedirectCallback.onRedirectVerifyCallback"`

Comment: Its weird so `throw Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED` is putting into console `uncaught exception: 2152398850  (unknown)`, while doing `throw new Error(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED` is putting into console `Error: 2152398850 bootrap.js:1990:5`. Eh it might be my develoepr preferences. I'll stop nitpicking lol.

Answer (score -1):

thx, the code works, but not as expected: `A->B->C->D (channel_1 -> channel_2 -> channel_3 -> channel_4).`

In my case it will record a redirect chain of `A->B->C->D` like:

`A->B (channel_1 -> channel_2), than B->C (channel_1 -> channel_2), C->D (channel_1 -> channel_2);` where `channel_1 & channel_2` are random hash numbers.

So I can not link the chain together. that would be the strategy to capture the chain of events (while the pages redirect using, meta-refresh, javascript, http...)?